# StringVar DoubleVar and others

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new on Python and I have a problem.
I try to read my temperature sensor and set the Value in to my Tkinter GUI.

I don't know how to update my label `LT` with the new value if I update it with my Button `B1`.

I have tried everything from `StringVar` to `get()` and this stuff.

I hope you can help me to find my failure.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

Main = Tk()
Main.title("HauptmenÃ¼")
Main.geometry("500x400")
class Fenster():

    def Credit():
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Credits",message="created by T.N v0.1")
        return

    def Beenden():
        pExit = messagebox.askyesno(title="Beenden",message="MÃ¶chten Sie\n wirklich beenden?")
        if pExit > 0:
            Main.destroy()
            return

    def auslesen(event):
        file = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041635ad4cff/w1_slave")
        inhalt = file.read()
        trennwoerter = inhalt.split(" ")
        Wert = (trennwoerter[20])
        Temp = (Wert[2:4])
        file.close()


    labelauslesen = Label(Main,text="Aktuelle Temperatur :")
    labelauslesen.pack()

    LT = Label(Main,text=Inhalt)
    LT.pack()

    B1 = Button(Main,text="Temperatur auslesen")
    B1.pack()
    B1.bind("<Button-1>",auslesen)

    menubar=Menu(Main)

    filemenu = Menu(menubar)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Sensoren auslesen")
    filemenu.add_command(label="Diagram anzeigen")
    filemenu.add_command(label="Credits",command = Credit)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Beenden",command = Beenden)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="Datei",menu=filemenu)

    Main.config(menu=menubar)


mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want the label to display after you click the button.

Comment: i want to label the temperature value that i get from "def auslesen"

Comment: file = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041635ad4cff/w1_slave")

and i want to display the data in the label

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Part of that is not using external files.  I will show the 'how' in a few minutes if no one else does.

Comment: thanks a lot!! it works pretty fine!

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example that you can adapt to your code.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

temp = 10.0
def update_temp():
    global temp
    temp += 1.3
    tlabel['text'] = '%s degrees C' % round(temp, 1)

tlabel = tk.Label(root, text='unknown')
tbutton = tk.Button(root, text='new temp', command=update_temp)
tlabel.pack()
tbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```